# Placing a web app into WordPress directory

Tags: wordpress

So I have a web app and a promotional website. Promotional website resides in the root of www.domain.com. I would like the web app (cakePHP framework) to be accessible at www.domain.com/app.

Just placing the app folder into the wp directory doesn't work.

What could be wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you browse to www.domain.com/app, Wordpress is going to go looking for a page or custom post type named app, and 404 when it doesn't find it. You need to add a rewrite rule to your .htaccess file for any requests in your /app folder to bypass Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the .htaccess file of your wordpress installation to pass through all requests to your /app/ folder without going through wordpress as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Let all go through to app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/app/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Normal Wordpress rewrites
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```